What evidence do we have for who this young man was? Mark 16:5
Mark 16:5

And entering the tomb, they saw a young man sitting at the right,
wearing a white robe; and they were amazed.

The common interpretation is that this is an angel. I’ve also heard that this could be an unidentified witness.
My question is: What evidence do we have, hermeneutical or otherwise, for who this young man was?

If one sees two messengers (in human appearance) then it is also true that one has seen one (human appearance).

We have a simple comparison of the gospel accounts:
Matthew 28

2 Suddenly there was a great earthquake, for an angel of the Lord descended from heaven, rolled away the stone, and sat on it. 3 His
appearance was like lightning, and his clothes were white as snow.
4The guards trembled in fear of him and became like dead men.
5 But the angel said to the women, “Do not be afraid, for I know that you are looking for Jesus, who was crucified. 6 He is not
here; He has risen, just as He said! Come, see the place where He lay.
7 Then go quickly and tell His disciples, ‘He has risen from the dead and is going ahead of you into Galilee. There you will see Him.’
See, I have told you.”

Mark 16

5 When they entered the tomb, they saw a young man dressed in a white robe sitting on the right side, and they were alarmed. 6 But
he said to them, “Do not be alarmed. You are looking for Jesus the
Nazarene, who was crucified. He has risen! He is not here! See the
place where they put Him. 7 But go, tell His disciples and Peter,
‘He is going ahead of you into Galilee. There you will see Him, just
as He told you.’ ”

Luke 24

4 While they were puzzling over this, suddenly two men in radiant apparel stood beside them.
5 As the women bowed their faces to the ground in terror, the two men asked them, “Why do you look for the living among the dead? 6
He is not here; He has risen! Remember how He told you while He was
still in Galilee: ...

John 20
John does not record anything about the women's conversation at the tomb.
We observe several things about the record as we have it:

the women were the first to arrive at the tomb
they wonder about how to remove the stone but find it already rolled aside
the women meet either one, "man" or two "men" or angels in bright shining clothes

The description of the angels at the tomb as "men" is common in Scripture as we see the same thing in other places as well such as:

Gen 18 & 19 - two of the "men" who met Abraham turn out to be angels (Gen 19:1.  Compare Heb 13:2.
the name "Gabriel" means "man of God"
Jacob wrestled a "man" (Gen 32:24) that turned out to be God (Gen 32:28, 30)
Joshua met and talked with a "man" (Josh 5:13) that turns out to be the commander of the LORD's army (V15) and the LORD Himself (V14, Josh 6:2)
a "man in white" is an angel or cherub, Eze 10:2, 6, 7
a man dressed linen is an angel of God, Dan 10:5, 16, 18.  See also Dan 12:7.


+1. I appreciate the simplicity yet full coverage of references!

Regarding the biblical evidence, @Dottard's answer is more than adequate. Among apocryphal testimonies, perhaps the most interesting is found in the Gospel of Peter. In this narrative Pilate sets soldiers to safeguard the tomb at the behest of Jewish leaders, fearing a miracle or a popular uprising. The young man of Mark 16 appears vs. 55. His clearly angelic counterparts are seen in vss. 36-40. They are gigantic, and the risen Christ's head reaches beyond the heavens:

[35] But in the night in which the Lord's day dawned, when the
soldiers were safeguarding it two by two in every watch, there was a
loud voice in heaven; [36] and they saw that the heavens were opened
and that two males who had much radiance had come down from there and
come near the sepulcher... [39] And while they
were relating what they had seen, again they see three males who have
come out from they sepulcher, with the two supporting the other one,
and a cross following them, [40] and the head of the two reaching unto
heaven, but that of the one being led out by a hand by them going
beyond the heavens...
[50] Now at the dawn of the Lord's Day Mary Magdalene, a female
disciple of the Lord... [51] having taken with her women friends, came
to the tomb where he had been placed....  [55] They found the
sepulcher opened. And having come forward, they bent down there and
saw there a certain young man seated in the middle of the sepulcher,
comely and clothed with a splendid robe, who said to them: [56] 'Why
have you come? Whom do you seek? Not that one who was crucified? He is
risen and gone away. But if you do not believe, bend down and see the
place where he lay, because he is not here. For he is risen and gone
away to there whence he was sent.' [57] Then the women fled
frightened.

Here the seemingly human young man stands in stark contrast to the supernatural beings who must certainly be angels. However, since scripture frequently refers to angels as "men" this does not constitute evidence that the young man is not an angel. And of course, the Gospel of Peter is not canonical. It appears to have combined two or more accounts and exaggerated them.

+1. I appreciate the reference!

What version are you using?
